# PHP Math Equation

Tags: php, math, variables

I am trying to write a math equation with PHP. The equation I need to write is:

(.0054 * 260000) / (1-1.0054^-360)

This equals: 1639.958570 (On my calculator)

With the script I am writing I have it as such:

```
$dec = .0054;
$amount = 260000;
$months = 360;

$equation = ($dec * $amount) / (1 - (1 + $dec)^-$months);

print $equation;
```

The answer I am getting when I do this is "-3.9"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [pow()](http://php.net/pow) function:

```
$equation = ($dec * $amount) / (1 - pow(1 + $dec, $months * -1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `^` for power. Whay you are doing now is that you XOR instead.

Use [pow](http://php.net/pow) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the caret symbol is not representative of an exponential operator in PHP. The ^ (caret) operator performs a bitwise exclusive-OR (XOR) on two integers

Example:

```
$equation = ($dec * $amount) / (1 - (pow(1 + $dec, -$months));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the ^ as a power function (it's a [bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)).

Take a look at the [pow()](http://us.php.net/pow) function instead.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$dec = .0054;
$amount = 260000;
$months = 360;

$equation = ($dec * $amount) / (1 - pow(1 + $dec,-$months));

print $equation;
```